# jQuery looking for scroll height code to determine when to add new items to lazy loading scrollable div [jsFiddle attached]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large array of items that I render with jQuery templates. I want to render 50 or so at a time, and show more when the user scrolls down. I'm trying to find the correct logic on working with the scroll bar. I am doing something like this, but the scrolling is still a bit wonky:

```
var listItems = this.buildItemList(this.list, regex);    
        var renderItems = this.renderItems;
        renderItems(listItems, wrapper, 50);                    
        wrapper.scroll(function() {
            // This works, but doesn't work quite right. Looks a bit wonky.
            if (wrapper.scrollTop() > .5 * wrapper.children().length * wrapper.children().first().outerHeight())
            {
                renderItems(listItems, wrapper, 30);
            }
        });
```

View this jsFiddle I wrote, it's a great example of what I need.

http://jsfiddle.net/8rWTg/32/

Here's what's not working for me. I want to items to get added when you're about 80% through the list, however, with the logic I made, it happens at varying points depending on the number of items in the list, and between browsers.

Comment: Define wonky. What's not working for you.

Comment: Have you seen a working example of this anywhere in the wild? My initial thought is that it is wonky because the list size changes, thus causing the scrollbar to "disconnect" with the mouse. I don't see how you could work around that because you have no control over the actual scrollbar/mouse interaction. The only thing I could think of would be to size the scrollable area to an estimated height (lots of empty space) and then use your lazy load.

Comment: yea, this is pretty common, i see it all over the web, i'll find you an example.

Answer (score 0):

So something similar to [Imgur's album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7RZ8.jpg)? If you look at [their code](http://imgur.com/include/js/album.js?31911), they have a function called `_levelReached` which is probably similar to what you want.